# Where is lib/main.dart in Android Studio?

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I am trying to learn Flutter and I am following this tutorial [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/test-drive?tab=androidstudio).

I was able to successfully able to set up flutter and I opened Android Studio and hit play and I see the template base app showing. The tutorial then asks me to edit lib/dart.main

But I do not see that file anywhere in the file tree to edit it... I feel Like I am missing something really obvious.

[image]

What's frustrating is I can see main.dart file is running but I cant find it in Android Studio to edit it in Android Studio...

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my issue! In the top left where it says "Android" I had to click the drop down and change it to "Project"

[image]

and now you can see the /lib directory :-)

[image]